# C# LINQ orderby

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have an Xelement containing a number of elements.

I have the following code to sort them:

```
var calculation = from y in x.Elements("row")
                 orderby y.Element("BUILD_ORDER").Value
                 select new
                 {
                     calcAttribute = y.Element("ELEMENT").Value

                 };
```

Which works fine, until BUILD_ORDER > 10, it orders 10 just after 1.

If I want it in strict numerical order, I case the element to an Int, is this the correct way to do it, or does LINQ have an inbuilt extension/method?

```
orderby Convert.ToInt32(y.Element("BUILD_ORDER").Value)
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093842/alphanumeric-sorting-using-linq-c/5093995#5093995

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ to Objects doesn't have the built in conversion, but LINQ to XML does:

```
var calculation = from y in x.Elements("row")
                  orderby (int) y.Element("BUILD_ORDER")
                  select new
                  {
                      calcAttribute = y.Element("ELEMENT").Value
                  };
```

Is there any reason why you're using an anonymous type though, rather than just selecting the value you want? For example:

```
var calculation = from y in x.Elements("row")
                  orderby (int) y.Element("BUILD_ORDER")
                  select y.Element("ELEMENT").Value;
```

Note that both of these will throw an exception if the BUILD_ORDER or ELEMENT subelements are missing. You can fix that using a conversion to `int?` instead of `int` for `BUILD_ORDER`, and a conversion to `string` for ELEMENT:

```
var calculation = from y in x.Elements("row")
                  orderby (int?) y.Element("BUILD_ORDER")
                  select (string) y.Element("ELEMENT");
```

This will still fail if BUILD_ORDER exists but can't be parsed as an integer of course.

If your data should *always* have these elements, the first form is better, as it'll detect any data errors earlier.

Comment: Just as a clarification this is because XElement has an operator overload for Explict Casting to type int as well as many other [XElement Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit(v=VS.90).aspx)

Comment: Why didn't I think of using the XElement's explicit casting behavior? This sort of thing is why I don't mind getting Skeeted. :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, the reason I am using the anonymous type is that my original code had a number of values being extracted that I needed to use.  I haven't changed the code yet.  As far as the errors are concerned - I have learned that multiple times today :)  I had never heard of (int?) before, I'll have a read up on that.  Thanks for the great answer.

Comment: @Jon, Google doesn't seem to be liking (int?), would you mind explaining how it work please?

Comment: @Darren: It's syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>`. Look up nullable value types in your favourite C# book or web page.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good to me.  You could also use `Int32.Parse(...)`.  I'm not aware of any built-in method for sorting strings as integers, but you certainly could write your own.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, since your XML values are not typed, you have to cast them manually for .NET to be able to sort numerically.

By the way, `int.Parse` will give you slightly better performance.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's reading the build order as a string instead of an int. Your sample should work, or try

```
orderby int.Parse(y.Element("BUILD_ORDER").Value)
```