# Sort Observable Collection Alpha-Numeric

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have an extension class that is converting an Observable collection to list and performing an order by. This logic is working but I need it to sort Alpha-numeric as well.  E.g.

In lieu of A1 A10 A2 A3 should be A1 A2 A3 A10.

What is the best way to go about this?

```
<pre>

public static void Sort<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        var comparer = new Comparer<T>(comparison);

        List<T> sorted = collection.OrderBy(x => x, comparer).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < sorted.Count(); i++)
            collection.Move(collection.IndexOf(sorted[i]), i);
    }


    internal class Comparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Comparison<T> comparison;

    public Comparer(Comparison<T> comparison)
    {
        this.comparison = comparison;
    }
    #region IComparer<T> Members

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {   
        return comparison.Invoke(x, y);
    }
}

</pre>
```

Comment: so, to be explicit, you're asking for an implementation of Comparison<T> that compares alphanumerically?

Comment: Correct, I need it to compare alphanumerically in lieu of just the string literal.

Comment: Any reason to not use the [sorting outlined here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting)?

Comment: Another [approach using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093842/alphanumeric-sorting-using-linq-c)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the `string` into two parts, the alpha part and the number part. Put the number part into an `int`, and then compare the int part only when the alpha part is a tie.

```
public int Compare(string left, string right) {
  string leftAlpha;
  int leftNum;
  string rightAlpha;
  int rightNum;

  GetParts(left, out leftAlpha, out leftNum);
  GetParts(right, out rightAlpha, out rightNum);

  if (leftAlpha != rightAlpha) {
     return String.Compare(leftAlpha, rightAlpha);
  }
  else {
     return leftNum.CompareTo(rightNum);
  }
}

private void GetParts(string str, out string alpha, out string num) {
  alpha = str.Substring(0, 1);
  string numStr = str.Substring(1);
  num = Int32.Parse(numStr);
}
```

---

If you can find a way to expose those two parts as properties on a class, you might be best off using a [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx) to bind to. Where the `SourceCollection` is your `ObservableCollection`, and then add `SortDescriptions` which correspond to the properties on the class. That could be overkill, but does have a lot of benefits like inserting new elements directly into the right position. You won't have to do any sorting on the collections explicitly at all.