# C# orderby string along with int

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list containing data with string and number. I have to order it in ascending and descending order.

```
        id    data
    ------------------
        1     data1@%
        2     data10
        3     data
        4     @$data
        5     data2
```

I fetch the record and store it in list "List". Then I order it in ascending, but "data10" is coming in b/w "data1" and "data2". Below is my code

```
var o/p = List.OrderBy(x => x.data);

expected output - data1, data2 and data10
```

Comment: order it by id instead

Comment: Yes, that's dictionary ordering.

Comment: I assume your code does not actually include `var o/p = ...`

Comment: i have to take the data column only

Comment: What result are you expecting? (the field is a `string` and is being ordered correctly)

Comment: @anand but the sequence you are getting will be data1, data10 and data2 if you order it by data.

Comment: create a new column by splitting the number from data and order by the new column you will get the desired result.

Comment: check my (@Nayan Godhani) answer it's works your need

Comment: Only solution is to retrieve a number from string and sort collection by this number. Which answers below provides. So main question is **how to retrieve numbers from string**. For answering this question you need provide more information about `data` value, is "data" part constant or it change, if it change then how it change etc... Of cource if it constant then use first option in @Abion47 answer.

Comment: @Fabio And if it's not constant, use the second option.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently sorting it based on the string values, which will sort it by dictionary value. In a dictionary, "10" will appear between "1" and "2" because that is alphabetical order - it does not recognize that it is sorting numbers.

True alphanumeric sorting can get pretty complex, but based on your data you might be able to simplify it. Assuming your string "data1", "data2", and "data10" is a consistent pattern, you can do something like this:

```
var op = List.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(x.data.substring(4)));
```

Alternatively, if the value before the number isn't a constant length, you can use Regex to pull the number value out:

```
var op = List.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(Regex.Match(x.data, "\\d+").Value));
```

Comment: if i put orderbydescending, the above will work right

Comment: error showing in "Regex"

Comment: Do you have `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`?

Comment: issue fixed after adding the package.

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want, you need to pad the numeric portion in your order by clause, something like:

```
var o/p = List.OrderBy(x => PadNumbers(x.Data));
```

where PadNumbers could be defined as StackOverflow user [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24954/nathan) has written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5093939/215380):

```
public static string PadNumbers(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(10, '0'));
}
```

This pads zeros for any number (or numbers) that appear in the input string so that OrderBy sees:

```
data0000000001
data0000000010
data0000000002
```

The padding only happens on the key used for comparison. The original strings (without padding) are preserved in the result.

Note : This approach assumes a maximum number of digits for numbers in the input.

Comment: can u explain the above code fn

Comment: Padding solution just move problem and not remove it. Converting number part to the integer will work in any case. No need for note of maximum amount of digits.

Comment: Please don't take another user's solution and present it as your own.