# C# Order by string along with int and special characters

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list containing data with string and number. I have to order it in ascending and descending order.

```
        id    data
    ------------------
        1     data1@%
        2     data10
        3     data
        4     @$data
        5     data2
```

I fetch the record and store it in list "List". Then I order it in ascending, but "data10" is coming in b/w "data1" and "data2". Below is my code

```
var o/p = List.OrderBy(x => x.data);
```

expected output — standard ascending order format.

Comment: You need Alphanumeric sorting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alphanumeric sorting using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093842/alphanumeric-sorting-using-linq)

Comment: There is no "standard" ascending order format. You can use the [comparisonType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter of the [String.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6883c06(v=vs.110).aspx) method to specify a specific comparison.

Comment: here the column contains alphanumeric, special characters, alpha

Comment: @anand  Doesn't matter, both the linked question's answers and Mrinal's answer will still work, because all it takes is treating the numeric part specially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How bout this, Copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093842/alphanumeric-sorting-using-linq)
Where list is your List variable.

```
var result = list.OrderBy(x => Regex.Replace(x, "[0-9]+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(10, '0')));
```

[image]

Comment: Good one, I assume it works for all the Alpha numeric scenarios +1, however as you are copying from another answer, please try to add your own explanation