# ASP.Net EF OrderBy not natural sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am writing to search function. My Db field as string (Nvarchar(MAX)) and this field have string and number

```
DB DATAS    EF ORDER          I want to
a 1          a 1                a 1
a 20         a 12               a 2
a 2          a 2                a 12
a 12         a 20               a 20
a 25         a 25               a 25
b 1          b 1                b 1
b 5          b 5                b 5
....         ...                ....
```

Comment: In LINQ you may use `OrderBy` followed with `ThenBy`, e.g. `list.OrderBy(x => x.LetterFieldName).ThenBy(x => x.NumericFieldName)`. If you want to perform further comparison, create a method extending `IComparer<int>` for numeric field and pass it in `OrderBy`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i have one field =>  `a 2`  data is only a column in  db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case (a letter followed with numbers), you may require number padding like this (credits to Nathan):

```
public static string PadNumbers(string input)
{
    // replace number "2" into number of digits you want to group with
    return Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(2, '0'));
}
```

This way enables padding on numeric portion in `OrderBy` clause, which should be used like this:

```
var naturalOrder = list.OrderBy(x => PadNumbers(x));
```

By using padding regex above, `OrderBy` will see the number part like this:

```
a 01
a 20
a 02
a 12
a 25
...
```

and then ordering them like this:

```
a 01
a 02
a 12
a 20
a 25
...
```

Of course, the padding only used in comparison when deciding number orders and the original strings still preserved.

The reason behind padding usage is the default ordering used with `OrderBy` in lexicographical order which process characters in string from left to right.

Working example: [NET Fiddle Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/popHU8)

Similar issue:

[Alphanumeric sorting using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093842/alphanumeric-sorting-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the IComparer interface and create a `NaturalStringComparer` to compare strings in the way you want. See code below.

```
public class NaturalStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private static readonly Regex _re = new Regex(@"(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        x = x.ToLower();
        y = y.ToLower();
        if (string.Compare(x, 0, y, 0, Math.Min(x.Length, y.Length)) == 0)
        {
            if (x.Length == y.Length) return 0;
            return x.Length < y.Length ? -1 : 1;
        }
        var a = _re.Split(x);
        var b = _re.Split(y);
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            int r = PartCompare(a[i], b[i]);
            if (r != 0) return r;
            ++i;
        }
    }

    private static int PartCompare(string x, string y)
    {
        int a, b;
        if (int.TryParse(x, out a) && int.TryParse(y, out b))
            return a.CompareTo(b);
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

Example for sorting mix of string and integers :

```
var x = new List<string>() { "a 1", "a 20", "a 2", "a 12" };
var y = x.OrderBy(m => m, new NaturalStringComparer()).ToList();
```

> Input : "a 1", "a 20", "a 2", "a 12"
>
> Output: "a 1", "a 2", "a 12", "a 20"

Comment: already i use it check the post and code area this middle list is EF orderby list

Comment: @OnePage : I have edited my answer. Please see the test example I have posted. It works fine for me and should suit your requirement too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
    var lists = strs.Select(str => new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)").Match(Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", "")))
        .Select(result => new
        {
            str = result.Groups[1].Value,
            num = result.Groups[2].Value
        })
        .ToList().OrderBy(s=>s.str).ThenBy(s=>s.num).Select(s=> new {result=s.str+" "+s.num}).ToList();
```

Comment: i have one field and this data one item

Comment: Is data ex:`a 1 ` contain space?@OnePage

Comment: Numeric value is specific. It may or may not be.