# How to sort List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> by numeric part of values?

Tags: c#, linq

```
var keyValuePairList = model.someDictionary.ToList();
keyValuePairList .OrderBy(r => r.Value);
```

The problem is sorting by alphanumeric values are not correct.

Output: CR1 CR10 CR11 CR2 CR20

Expected: CR1 CR2 CR10 CR11 CR20

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I looked many solutions including the possible duplicate you suggested above but in my case its List<string,string> which makes it different. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @VijayendraShah - You **don't** have a `List<key, value>` or a `List<string, string>`, because that's not possible (apart from creating your own type...). You **do** (probably) have a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, but that's not the point. Why don't you just do something like `yourDictionary.OrderBy(entry => MagicMethodThatWorksForLists(entry.Value))` where the "magic method" might be something like the `PadNumbers` method in the linked thread?

Comment: Are your inputs always "CR" followed by a stringified integer?  If so, look at @ZevSpitz's answer.  If not, is the pattern "two apha characters" followed by an integer, or maybe "N alpha characters" followed by an integer.  If it's one of the latter two cases, you need to establish a sort order (alphas first then integer, or the other way around).  Then you need to find a way to split the strings (a Regex would probably do it).  Once you do that, sorting is pretty easy.

Comment: @VijayendraShah - again the question: you seem to have found solutions for `List<string>`, what makes you think those same solutions won't work on `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`? (Or `Dictionary<string, string>` or basically *any* `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Whatever, string>>`)

Comment: @Corak Thanks.....I followed your suggestion and Padding worked. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If every string starts with two alphabetical characters, I would use the following:

```
keyValuePairList.OrderBy(r => int.Parse(r.Value.Substring(2)));
```

Otherwise, use a regular expression, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51665173/111794).

```
var re = new  Regex(@"\d+$");
keyValuePairList.OrderBy(x => int.Parse(re.Match(x.Value).Value));
```

Comment: Its not always CR it might be a normal string of any length or an alphanumeric string.

Comment: @VijayendraShah In the future, this is important information which should be included in the question. In any event, I refer you to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51665173/111794) on the linked duplicate question.