# Order a List<T> naturally using a property of T naturally

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sorting

I am attempting to sort a List of fuses by the Designator property of the fuse.

**The Fuse Model:**

```
public class Fuse
{
    public string Designator { get; set; }

    public string Rating { get; set; }

    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

**Example Data**

This is an example of what a list of fuses would look like.

[image]

**What I have tried:**

```
fuses = fuses.OrderBy(f => f.Designator).ToList();
```

The above code sort of works, but it puts the F10 before F2. Does anyone know of a way to sort a List by the designator appropriately? I have read about natural sorting algorithms but not quite sure how to apply them correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp

Comment: you would need to parse the property into a sortable weight using a comparer to get the desired behavior. currently it is sorting it as a string. where 10, comes before 2

Comment: It seems like a somewhat specific string comparison, first taking the letter then comparing by the parsed number afterwards. For cases like these, I'd suggest creating a custom IComparer<string> and using it in an OrderBy overload.

Comment: Would it be possible for a example implementation of this?

Comment: Is the `Designator` code a fixed format? Always 1 letter A-Z + a whole number?

Comment: Yes, it is actually Always F + whole numbers. Sometimes could appear as F1,F2,F3 or F1-F3. Also, fuses can't repeat, you would never have a situation like F1-F3 and F3-F5.

Comment: @Selthien Did you check the link in the first comment?

Comment: Do you always want to sort based on the first `Designator` value in the range?

Comment: @Igor yes that is correct. I checked the first link but not quite sure how to implement it with a List. Makes sense if you want to compare two strings.

Comment: [Alphanumeric sorting using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093842/alphanumeric-sorting-using-linq)

Comment: @Selthien The first link **does have your answer**, you just need to pass an instance of the comparer class to the `OrderBy` method. [Here's a complete example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wyocn3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only compare string `F2` the order will greater than `F10`.

You can try to `order by` number by `Regex`.

use `^F(\d+)` pattern to get the number then order by.

```
fuses = fuses.OrderBy(f => int.Parse(Regex.Match(f.Designator, @"^F(\d+)").Groups[1].Value)).ToList();
```

Comment: votedowner Is there any reason ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [`IComparable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
class Fuse : IComparable<Fuse>
{
    public string Designator { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(Fuse other)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(other?.Designator)) return -1;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Designator)) return 1;
        if (this.Designator == other.Designator) return 0;

        // get the first item in the range
        var d1Str = this.Designator.Split(new[] {',', '-'})[0];
        var d2Str = other.Designator.Split(new[] {',', '-'})[0];

        // parse to int
        var d1 = int.Parse(d1Str.Substring(1));
        var d2 = int.Parse(d2Str.Substring(1));

        return d1 > d2 ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

Test code

```
var list = new List<Fuse>()
{
    new Fuse{Designator = "F8,F9"},
    new Fuse{Designator = "F1,F2,F3"},
    new Fuse{Designator = "F10-F12"},
    new Fuse{Designator = "F4-F7"},
};

foreach (var itm in list.OrderBy(_ => _))
{
    Console.WriteLine(itm.Designator);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output

```
F1,F2,F3
F4-F7
F8,F9
F10-F12
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to sort it by integer instead. Throw away first letter, parse as integer and sort by this integer.

```
f => Int32.Parse(f.Designator.Substring(1))
```

Of course you can always refactor it out of lambda into something else.

Comment: @PoulBak And what the problem with that? It handles any length

Comment: It will fail when there are more than one value in Designator (because it will include an 'F' Again).

Comment: Yes, I assumed it's single-value enum.