# how do find the same string and difference string in List<string>?

Tags: c#, list

I have list like this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>() 
{
    "AS2258B43C014AI9954803",
    "AS2258B43C014AI9954603",
    "AS2258B43C014AI9954703",
    "AS2258B43C014AI9954503",
    "AS2258B43C014AI9954403",
    "AS2258B43C014AI9954203",
    "AS2258B43C014AI9954303",
    "AS2258B43C014AI9954103",
 };
```

I want to output something format is  sameString+diffString0\diffString1\diffString2.... like this "AS2258B43C014AI9954803\603\703\503\403\203\303\103"

what should I do?

Comment: what are you tried ?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you have something like `"AS2258B43C014AI9954108"` also in your list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method which returns you the difference between to strings:

```
private static string GetDiff (string s1, string s2)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < Math.Min(s1.Length,s2.Length); i++)
        {
            if(s1[i] != s2[i])
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return s2.Substring(i);
    }
```

This method iterats until the first character which is different and returns the remaining characters of the second string.

With that method, you can obtain your result with the LINQ query:

```
string first = myList[0];
string result = first + "/" + string.Join("/", myList.Skip(1).Select(x => GetDiff(first,x)));
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TPkhmz

Answer (score 0):

[Alphanumeric sorting using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5093842/alphanumeric-sorting-using-linq)

Create static method for pads

```
 public static string PadNumbers(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Replace(input, "[0-9]+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(10, '0'));
    }
```

then call it

```
 var result = myList.OrderBy(x => PadNumbers(x));
```

[image: example]

after that you can find the difference

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create a function like this :

```
public static string Output(List<String> ListString)
{
  string sameString = ListString.First().Substring(0, 18);
  string output = sameString;
  foreach (var item in ListString)
  {
    output += item.Substring(19);
    output += "\\";
  }

  return output.Substring(0, output.Length - 1);
}
```